# What's the alternative for BufferedWriter in Java NIO

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

If we are using Java Standard IO api's to read a file line by line and manipulate line and write it to a new file. We would be using a snippet something like this.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
String str;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //... code for manipulation of str
    bw.write(str);
    bw.newLine();
}
```

I require a readlock on the file that is getting written, So I proceeded to use FileChannel in Java NIO package. In order to achieve the same. The code snippet I have written is below.

```
int blocksize = 32 * 1024;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath), inputCharset));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
FileChannel outputFileChannel = fos.getChannel();
outputFileChannel.lock();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(blocksize);
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    buffer.put(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    buffer.put("\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    buffer.flip();
    outputFileChannel.write(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
}
br.close();
outputFileChannel.close();
fos.close();
```

Now my question is how much this is affecting performance, is Filechannel would be writing to file everytime we call *filechannel.write* (I mean is it exactly behaves like filereader.write)or will it be internally using a buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use BufferedWriter and FileChannel.lock().

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
FileLock lock = fis.getChannel().lock();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
String str;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //... code for manipulation of str
    bw.write(str);
    bw.newLine();
}
lock.release();
```

Comment: That works fine, but aren't we leaking resource, when we do fis.getChannel() as we are getting a channel and never using it and also we have 2 handles on the same file.

Comment: @saiki4116 The FileChannel uses the same underlying FileDescriptor as the FileInputStream so there is only one file resource.